# Which tool is more suitable for visualizing the distribution of multiple real and synthetic image datasets, t-SNE or PCA?

Tags: pca, data-visualization, computer-vision, tsne, synthetic-data

I am doing a thesis on the generation of synthetic data for training a deep learning model and evaluating it on real data. I have a few different real datasets, and I generated multiple synthetic datasets with different parameters. I want to write a chapter with data description and would like to be able to visualize them. But I am wondering which tool would make more sense, t-SNE or PCA. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to obtaining a visual representation of samples' variability/similarity, I think it really depends on the scope, but I'd probably favor t-SNE over PCA given that the data is perceptual and thus likely to contain non-linear patterns.

Have you considered plotting embeddings of your images instead of the raw data? If you are applying auto-encoders or VAEs the latent representation could be a nice input for visualization. Also, if you go down the t-SNE path, you might want to check UMAP as well (this [nice post](https://pair-code.github.io/understanding-umap/) could be a good starting point). Good luck with your thesis!

Comment: Thanks for the comment! 
Yes, I should have mentioned in the post. I was thinking exactly about using embeddings. In this case, do you still favor t-SNE?

Comment: I would try the following then: do the PCA on the embeddings, check the elbow plot, and keep only the components that explain say, 95% of the variance. Visualize the first few PCs to get an idea of how the samples are captured. Then do t-SNE on those first n PCs (the ones that explain the majority of the variance), and check the result. This is a known strategy that should get rid of unwanted noise, and lets you also check both dimensionality reductions in the process.

Comment: That is a great idea, I ll check that. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, do you know some paper that does something similar to what you described? I think it would be good to have a reference to justify doing that

Comment: This is something I often see in my field (high dimensional gene expression data), like in this [vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/articles/pbmc3k_tutorial.html), see the " Determine the ‘dimensionality’ of the dataset" section. 

However, it might be only a practical way to fasten up the t-SNE/UMAP reducing the features. I don't know whether the result would be better by running on PCs instead of raw embeddings. In your case your embedding might be already reduced in dimension, so applying directly t-SNE should be feasible and my suggestion on doing PCA first might be out of scope!

Comment: Cool, thanks for the insights. I am trying UMAP as well, I didnt know it before but it seems pretty useful + runs faster than tsne